# A library to convert SVG to EMF

Tags: open-source, library, python, vector-graphics

I need a library, preferably Python or C, to provide conversion of SVG (Scaled Vector Graphics) to Microsoft EMF (Enhanced Meta File).

### Desirable Characteristics

- Open Source (Preferably MIT licence or similar)
- Windows or Cross Platform
- Support all/most SVG constructs
- **Not** convert to bitmap and then EMF or similar - the results must still be a vector format.

Comment: Can it be a desktop app that can be accessed through CLI? I'm thinking of Inkscape. I think Ghostscript might also fit the bill

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos - given some of the constraints I would prefer a library if one exists - all of the solutions I have found so far tend to be applications with a CLI (or headerless mode).

Comment: Well then maybe either Ghostscript or ImageMagic, never tried them myself